# socket.io callback is not being called

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Doing some socket.io work. Seems like my emit callback is not being fired. Am I doing it right?

```
this.logger.debug("joining room " + roomId);      
callback = function() {
  return this.logger.debug('finished emitting join for socket');
};
// this.config.ioTypes.join resolves to "j"
this.socket.emit(this.config.ioTypes.join, { 
  user: this.config.user,
  room: roomId
}, callback);
```

My logging looks correct (note that the code above doesn't include everything that would generate these logs):

```
DEBUG: joining room 1245 <-- first line from code above
DEBUG: join event for socket etQIXGAm59DYkCPk1_gj 
DEBUG: data: { user: 1, room: '1245' }             
DEBUG: received join event for 1, data: { user: 1, room: '1245' }
```

And that's the end. It looks like socket.io is not calling my callback. But the docs are pretty clear:

> Sometimes, you might want to get a callback when the client confirmed
>   the message reception.
>
> To do this, simply pass a function as the last parameter of `.send` or
>   `.emit`. What's more, when you use `.emit`, the acknowledgement is
>   done by you, which means you can also pass data along:

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out on my own. Gonna leave this here because the docs aren't very clear on this one.

I used `util.inspect(arguments)` to see what was coming in to my `on` handler on the server side (coffeescript):

```
  @logger.debug "onJoin args: " + util.inspect(arguments)
```

Which resulted in: `...  '2': [Function: ack]` which looked like what I needed. So I added that to the signature of the `on` handler. Then I added `callback() if callback?` to the end of the handler. Looks good so far.

Comment: Can you elaborate?, I'm seeing the same issue but don't see the solution here.

Comment: on code from 2 months ago? looks like I had to manually call the callback in my on handler.

Comment: Ahh, I may be having a different issue - I've been digging and finding that my socket.io callbacks aren't called if I am running on Heroku with more than 1 server.

Comment: hmmm, try logging the args? maybe the callback isn't coming in to the responder.